# Tomcat instance inadvertently down in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, java

I am running a tomcat instance in my ec2-instance, and it is frequently down for some reason. I checked the logs at {tomcatinstance}/logs/ , like catalina.out, localhost*.log, myapplication.log; but there are no traces of why it is going down. I also tried the see if any jvm crash logs available "hs_err*". but there aren't any.

i tried to find if any oom killer did something

sudo egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages, did return me nothing

how can I go about resolving this issue.

Comment: Did you check /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/syslog

Comment: +1 Sounds like a case of the Linux out of memory killer

Comment: I checked the var/log/messages there are no traces

Comment: I have installed it under /usr/local. will there be any issues with that